# Getting the value from the button in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an html component button like

```
<button>Add to cart</button>
```

Now I want to get the text in the button i.e Add to cart..

How can i get this value in the script. On clicking this button will pass an event to windows click event listener. Inside that i want to get this value.

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        console.log('window noticed you clicked something1');
        console.log("value of the element clicked== "+target.text());
        console.log(target);//<-- this is the element that was clicked
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Check out [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Check the answer which has been posted. You will get a lot of idea from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to write your HTML outside of `<script>`. Secondly, you need click on button so assign the button an `id` and then bind click event on it. HTML will be

```
<button id='addToCart'>Add to cart</button>
```

And javascript will be

```
document.getElementById('addToCart').addEventListener('click',function(e)
        {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            console.log('window noticed you clicked something1');
            console.log("value of the element clicked== "+target.innerText);
            console.log(target);//<-- this is the element that was clicked
        }, false);
```

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LL1a1tLb/2/)

You can also use `innerHTML` like

```
console.log("value of the element clicked== "+target.innerHTML);
```

Comment: this is giving console log even when we click outside of button

Comment: Yes it will give as there is a bind of click in windows. And stop arguing on my answer as i commented on yours. Don't have a revenge or jealousy feeling mate.

Comment: No offence , but I didn't observe that you commented

Comment: Please also upvote it if you really found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one button you can try `getElementsByTagName`, if u have multiple buttons you can define id and use `document.getElementById`

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].innerHTML);

console.log(document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML);
```

```html
<button>Add to Cart</button>
<button id="myButton">Add to Cart2</button>
```

Comment: The value should be displayed on click of button. Not on page load.

Comment: I just showed how we can access value , we can call this even in click listener or function

Comment: But it is not the actual way you give answer. If people started giving answers like you did there will be plenty of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<button class="myButton">Add to cart</button>


<script>

var buttonValue = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(buttonValue);


window.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        console.log('window noticed you clicked something1');
        console.log("value of the element clicked== "+target.innerHTML);
        console.log(target);//<-- this is the element that was clicked
}, false); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading value of the button.

```
    console.log(target.value);//<-- this is the element that was clicked
```